# How define formally a user-defined binary operation?

Tags: functions, notation, binary-operations, index-notation

Let $x \in \{0,1\}^{|\mathcal{S}|}$ and $k \in \{0,1\}^{|\mathcal{R}|}$, where their elements are indexed by the index sets $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ respectively. The index sets satisfy $\mathcal{R} \subset \mathcal{S}$. I would like to define, formally, a binary (elementwise) operation $f(x,k,\mathcal{R})$ such that, for any $j \in \mathcal{S}$, 
\begin{align}
y(j) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x(j) & \text{if } x \in \mathcal{R}, \\
x(j) \oplus k(j) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}

Above, I have defined the binary operation for each index $j \in \mathcal{R}$, but I want to define formally the function that applies to the entire vector $x$.

Thank you.

Comment: Where you have "$\text{if } x\in \mathcal{R}$" should that be" $\text{if } j\in \mathcal{R}$" ? If so, what is $k(j)$ in the second half of the definition, when $j \notin \mathcal{R}$ ?

Comment: Could you specify the range of your binary operation? If you prefer, if you write $f: \{0,1\}^{|S|} \times  \{0,1\}^{|R|} \to  \{0,1\}^{?}$, what should be "?" ?

Comment: Sorry, there are some mistakes in the previous definition. The function $f$ is such that $f : \{0,1\}^{|\mathcal{S}|} \times \{0,1\}^{|\mathcal{R}|} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{|\mathcal{S}|}$. And the binary operation is defined, for any $j \in \mathcal{S}$, as
\begin{align}
y(j) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x(j) \oplus k(j) & \text{if } x \in \mathcal{R}, \\
x(j) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
Thus, "otherwise" means $j \in \mathcal{S} \setminus \mathcal{R}$.